# WebGL not working correctly in Rocky 9.3 VM

Tags: linux, vmware-workstation, webgl

I am working on Windows 11, where I have VMware Workstation 17.5, with a VM running Linux Rocky 9.3. I am testing my web app that uses Plotly.js 2.27.0 and the scattergl plots (using WebGL) don't work there:

- Firefox 115 - https://get.webgl.org/ displays the cube, but the scattergl plots are broken
- Chrome 120 -  https://get.webgl.org/ either says WebGL is not supported or it says it is supported, but does not display the cube, scattergl plots just say WebGL is not supported. I tries also to force enable WebGL but it did not help.

This problem is not present on Rocky 9.0, when using the same setup, only on Rocky 9.2 and 9.3 (have not tested 9.1).

Also when Rocky 9.3 is installed directly on HW, the issue does not occur.